# How to draw Isosceles Triangle in Java using only two for loops?

Tags: java

I can able to draw this pattern triangle using 3 for-loops but I want to draw using only 2 for-loops.

```
1 

1 2 

1 2 3 

1 2 3 4 

1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 4 5 6 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

1 2 3 4 5 6 

1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 4 

1 2 3 

1 2 

1
```

Program of Mine with 3 for loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Isotrg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.println("Enter the No. Line:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < (2 * n) - 1; i++)
        {
            int d = 1;
            if (i < n)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(d + " ");
                    d++;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < (2 * n) - i; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(d + " ");
                    d++;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hint `Math.abs`

Comment: In general, it is better to show the work you've already done, and highlight the areas that you're having problems with, rather than simply posting an open question like this looking to have the code provided to you. If you update your post, chances are you'll find better feedback. Have a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page for pointers.

Comment: `for (int column = 1; column <= row && column <= 14 - row; column++)`

Comment: I have updated my program..Can you tell me now how to write it with 2 loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as given is already doing all the right steps to print the triangle correctly. The key to focus on here is the stopping condition of your for loop. When `i < n` (in this case, when `i` is less than 7), you don't want `j` to exceed `i`. When `i` is greater than `n`, you don't want `j` to exceed `2n - i`.

So, considering both of these conditions jointly, you want `j` to be less than `i` AND you want it to be less than `2n - i`. Simply join the two conditions using the [logical AND operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You'll also have to adjust the bounds of your loop appropriately, checking the relative values of `i` and `j` at both ends to ensure they're lining up appropriately:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    System.out.println("Enter the No. Line:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i < (2 * n); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i && j <= (2 * n) - i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Additionally, notice that you can remove the unnecessary intermediate variable `d`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n=6;
for (int i=0; i<2*n+1; ++i)
{
    int k=Math.min(i, 2*n+-i);
    for (int j=0; j<=k; ++j)
    {
        System.out.print(j+1 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually print anything except for newlines... take another look at your for loop conditions. Additionally, you'll want `n=7`, rather than `n=6`, to get the desired output.

Comment: No, I want 'n=6', as there are '2*n+1' (=13) lines written. Of course you could also do the same with 1-based for Loops instead of my proposal of 0-based ones.
`int n=7; for (int i=1; i<2*n-1; ++i)` and so on shifting everything

Comment: @ManojKumar After the 2 typos in the inner loop nbrooks pointed out, I get the output:
<pre>
1
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 
1
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
int n=7;
for(int i=1;i<2*n;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=Math.min(i,2*n-i);j++)
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```